# How to change to another image when mouseover using Views?

Tags: 7, views, theming, javascript

I need to change the big image "A" to "D" when mouseover thumbnail "D" in a view (using [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)).

How can I do this? Preproces page or jquery in a custom text in view?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can try [Views Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) module with its ThumbnailHover slide feature. You can find its full documentation page in [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/755010).

Basically create a view with fields and a pager, set it as slider (Content: *slide*) and check *Activate slide and pause on pager hover* option.

For more details, see: [What you'll need to crete a jQuery slideshow in Drupal](http://www.bentedder.com/create-an-easy-jquery-slideshow-in-drupal-7/).